# Java String vs StringBuilder

Tags: java, string, performance, concatenation

As far as i know `+ operator` in Java String is overloaded and while we are using `+` operator it automatically chooses StringBuffer or StringBuilder to concatenate strings with better performance. Only exception of this is while we are using `+` operator inside a loop. In this case Java doesn't use benefits of StringBuffer and StringBuilder. Is that true? I will concatenate 40 Strings (around 4500 chars) and I will repeat it so often so I wanted be sure about it.

Comment: Why just don't use StringBuilder and append strings to it ?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

No, Java will <s>always</s> (almost always, see comment bellow) convert concatenation into the `StringBuilder`. However the problem with loop is that it will create new instance of `StringBuilder` per each walkthrough.

So if you do `String someString = i + "something";` inside the loop which goes from `0` to `1000` it will create for you new instance of `StringBuilder` 1000 times. Which could be a performance problem then. So just declare `StringBuilder` before the loop and then use it inside it.

Comment: Actually I will create a JSON and i will not use a loop for that so i am trying to figure out if its good idea to use StringBuilder or its not necessary.

Comment: Usually it's not needed, JVM is very good in stuff like that :)

Comment: +1, although the first sentence is incorrect: `No, Java will always convert concatenation into the StringBuilder`. In some cases the compiler leaves it as a String. ([source 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1532499/1682559) - comment in this answer; [source 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) - actual specs (quote: 'To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler **may** use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.').

Answer (score 2):

- String is **immutable**   while StringBuilder is **mutable**  it means when you create a String you can never change it
- String is thread safe  while StringBuilder not
- String stores in Constant String Pool  while StringBuilder in Heap

When you loop

`oldString  =  oldString + somechars,`

it means you create a new String and put oldString`s value into it first ,then append somechars ,then redirect the oldString variable to the result