# Java list visualization

Tags: java, list, geojson, tostring

i've a `List<Polygon> polygons`, where Polygon represents the geojson concept of polygon. In the class Polygon i defined a method `toGeojson()` that returns a string containing the geojson representation. I'd like to print all the list in a compact way instead of doing this:

```
String result = '';
for(Polygon p: polygons)
   result += p.toGeojson();
```

I could do `result = p.toString()` but i cannot use `toString()` method because i use it for an other thing. Is there a way to call `toGeojson()` on a List just as you'd do with `toString()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to convert an ArrayList to a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599161/best-way-to-convert-an-arraylist-to-a-string)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if that answers your question, but you can use `Stream` api for that thing.

```
String result = polygons.stream()
        .map(Polygon::toGeojson)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

There is no direct way to override behaviour of `List.toString()`.

**updated**
There is [Collectors#joining(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence prefix, CharSequence suffix)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method which accepts suffix and prefix. Using this method we can make our output look exactly like `List.toSting`  with square brackets.

```
String result = polygons.stream()
            .map(Polygon::toGeojson)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")); // ["x","y"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you want, but I guess you are looking for a way to print the geoJson representation of each `Polygon` contained in your List. In that case I don't see a better way than a loop, but avoid `String` concatenation inside loops. Use `StringBuilder` instead which has [much better performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624421/java-string-vs-stringbuilder).

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
for (Polygon p: polygons) {
   result.append(p.toGeojson());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the best, i think... In Java there is no faster solution and the Array.toString method works the same way.